# AWSで複数サービスへの振り分け方法

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

AWSでWebサービスの実装を検討しています。
同じドメインで異なるサービスに振り分けるということをしたいです。
ウェブアプリをEC2にデプロイすることを考えた場合にどのような構成で振り分けることができるでしょうか。

##### 現在考えている案

- サブドメインをROUTE53で追加して、サブドメインごとに異なるウェブアプリを振り分ける
- ルーティングサーバー(EC2)上にルーティング用のロジック(urlによってルーティング先を変更する)が実装されたアプリケーションを配置

##### 確認したいこと

- 上記の方針で実装可能か
- この他にAWSのサービスを使えばもっと簡単にできるなどあれば教えてほしい

Answer (score 1):

> - ルーティングサーバー(EC2)上にルーティング用のロジック(urlによってルーティング先を変更する)が実装されたアプリケーションを配置

は[Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/elasticloadbalancing/application-load-balancer/)を使うと、urlによって振り分けることができます。

加えて、今どきのサービスではSSLがほぼ必須かと思いますが、[AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/certificate-manager/)であればApplication Load Balancer向けに無償で証明書が発行できます。（EC2向けには発行できません。）

> - サブドメインをROUTE53で追加して、サブドメインごとに異なるウェブアプリを振り分ける

こちらは判断できません。AWSどうこうよりもDNSに関する知識が求められるかもしれません。